# Django URL appending to oneanother

Tags: python, django, url

I am having a problem understanding what is going on in Django. I created a delete function that supposedly deletes a record based on the DB record id. Upon deletion, I want to redirect to the same page I pressed the 'delete' button. However, when I look at the URL in the browser, it now contains an appended version of the two views. I will show my code below for clarity:

urls.py:

```
url(r'entry/current/$', views.current_entry_list, name='current_entry_list'),
url(r'^entry/create/$', views.create_entry_form_view, name='create_entry'),
url(r'update/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.update_entry_view, name='update_entry'),
url(r'delete/$', views.delete_entry_view, name='delete_entry'),
```

View delete method:

```
def delete_entry_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        id = request.POST['id']
        Entry.objects.filter(id=id).delete()

    return redirect('entry/current/')
```

View list records method:

```
def current_entry_list(request):
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    month = now.month
    current_entries = Entry.objects.filter(input_date__month=11).order_by('-
    input_date').all()
    for entry in current_entries:
        print(entry)
    paginator = Paginator(current_entries, 10)

    page = request.GET.get('page') 

    try:
        current_entries = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        current_entries = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        current_entries = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    context = {
        'current_entries': current_entries,
        'current_month': month,
    }
    return render(request, 'finance/entry.html', context)
```

Here is what my URL in the browser looks like:
127.0.0.1:8000/finance/delete/entry/current/

Why does the redirected view URL appends to the previous URL? Is there anyway i can replace completely?

Answer (score 1):

Django is treating the redirect `return redirect('entry/current/', permanent=True)` as a relative address and therefore appending the two.

If it is changed to `return redirect('/entry/current/', permanent=True)` it will take you back to the root URL.

The better approach is to use `reverse` on the URL name:

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.shortcuts import redirect

def delete_entry_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        id = request.POST['id']
        Entry.objects.filter(id=id).delete()
    return redirect(reverse('current_entry_list'), permanent=True)
```

The code that handle the relative URLs in `reverse` can be found at `django.shortcuts.resolve_url`.

Comment: I have tried, but i get this error instead: Reverse for 'current_entry_list' not found. 'current_entry_list' is not a valid view function or pattern name. Seems like the first method works, but that would mean i have to manually append `/finance/` to the `entry/current/` for it to work

Comment: Are your URLs included in another `urls.py` file with a namespace? If so it will need to change to `return redirect(reverse('<namespace>:current_entry_list'), permanent=True)`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe change:

```
return redirect('entry/current/')
```

To:

```
return redirect('/entry/current/')
```

OR

```
 return redirect(reverse('current_entry_list'), permanent=True)
```

which I think is the better approach.